# Science fiction or horror anthology book/audiobook about a science project robot that takes over a town

Tags: story-identification, horror, anthology-book

I'm looking to find the name or title of this book/audiobook from my childhood (I listened to it 1000 times in 1997). The main site was that 2 siblings have to fight one of their science projects (either a robot or a computer) after it becomes self aware. It starts taking over all electronics and proceeds to take over the town they live in.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *'Oh No!: Or How My Science Project Destroyed the World'* (2010) by Mac Barnett?

> When an overambitious little girl builds a humongous robot for the
> science fair, she fully expects to win first place. What she doesn't
> expect is the chaos that follows. Full color. Two major bestselling
> and award-winning picture book creators combine forces in this kid's
> eye account of a science fair gone horribly and hilariously awry!
>
> Some kids are too smart for their own good...and maybe for everybody
> else's good. When an overly ambitious little girl builds a humongous
> robot for her science fair, she fully expects to win first place. What
> she doesn't expect is the chaos that follows! "I probably shouldn't
> have given it a superclaw, or a laser eye, or the power to control
> dogs' minds," she laments. Kids, don't try this at home!
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

This could only be the answer if you have misremembered the story slightly, but how about [The Tomorrow City](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/682611.The_Tomorrow_City) by Monica Hughes?

The children are Caro and David and the computer was not a school science project but was invented by the Caro's father as a way of helping to run the city. When Caro's father leaves town for a while the computer takes over the city and starts brainwashing the inhabitants through their TVs. Caro and David were out playing when this happened so they escaped being brainwashed, and it's up to them to fight the computer.